# Set a static element as the last one in a Dropdown list?

Tags: angular

I have this code for sorting. Inside this data, I have an element call 'other' and I want that this element always remains the last one.

```
     getallIndustries() {
    this.customerService.getAppIndustry()
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.industries$ = this.sortData(data);
        },
        error => this.errMsg = error,
      );
  }

  sortData(value) {
    return value.sort((a, b) => {
      const itemA = a.name.toUpperCase();
      const itemB = b.name.toUpperCase();
      return itemA.localeCompare(itemB);
    });
  }
```

I try something like this :

```
    if (a.name === 'OTHER') {
  return 1;
}
if (a.name > b.name) {
  return 1;
}
if (a.name < b.name) {
  return -1;
}
return 0;
```

}

this is my array list:`0: "Agriculture and Mining"
1: "Business Services"
2: "Computer and Electronics"
3: "Consumer Services"
4: "Education"
5: "Energy and Utilities"
6: "Financial Services"
7: "Government"
8: "Health, Pharmaceuticals, and Biotech"
9: "Manufacturing"
10: "Media and Entertainment"
11: "Non-profit"
12: "Other"
13: "Real Estate and Construction"
14: "Retail"
15: "Software and Internet"
16: "Telecommunications"
17: "Transportation and Storage"
18: "Travel Recreation and Leisure"
19: "Wholesale and Distribution"`

but somehow this does not work, cause I am using the same function somewhere else and it works good, Can anyone help me, please.

I try even directly on the parent :

```
      getAppIndustry(): Observable<IIndustry[]> {
    return this.http.get<IIndustry[]>(this.getIndustry_Url)
      .pipe(
        map((res: IIndustry[]) => {
          console.log('ress eshte '+ res);
          return res.sort((a, b) => this.compareCategories(a, b));
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError),
      );
  }

  private compareCategories(a: IIndustry, b: IIndustry) {
    if (a.name === 'Other') {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Your approach should work, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfj6gg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: isn't working that's the problem

Comment: Please make a stackblitz showing how it doesn't work.

Comment: the dropdown list is  not changing the other is still sort by alphabet, not in the end

Comment: We should see the dropdown markup and code in the question. The code currently shown in the question appears to work well.

Comment: So if you edit your example in  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfj6gg?file=src/app/app.component.ts you will see that is not working

Comment: [ { "name": "Agriculture and Mining" }, { "name": "Business Services" }, { "name": "Computer and Electronics" }, { "name": "Other" }, { "name": "Software and Internet" }, { "name": "Telecommunications" }, { "name": "Wholesale and Distribution" } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sorting function keeps the item with the name "Other" in the last position:

```
sortData(value) {
  return value.sort((a, b) => {
    const itemA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const itemB = b.name.toUpperCase();
    if (itemA === "OTHER") {
      return 1;
    } else if (itemB === "OTHER") {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return itemA.localeCompare(itemB);
    }
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfj6gg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: i know that works cause i am using somewhere else this but here i don't know how or why doesn't work if you have team view you can see by your self

Comment: do you think this is an influence that does not work :  industries$: Observable<IIndustry[]>;

Comment: Did you notice that I modified the function? I added the condition where `itemB` is equal to `"OTHER"`. The code here works with the data that you supplied in the question.

Comment: I had already tried that  not working but because they save maybe in a simple array, my array is industries$: Observable<IIndustry[]>

Comment: Your observable returns a `IIndustry[]` and that array is sorted with the sorting method. By the way, the code examples in your question are different from the code in my answer. I don't know how you can say that you already tried my code. I can check with TeamViewer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the element from the array, sort the array, and put it back at the end/beginning :

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Christie' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Zachary' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Miguel' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Henri' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Cassidy' },
  { id: -1, name: 'Other' }
];

const staticEl = data.find(el => el.name === 'Other'); // Or use ID to find

const sorted = [...data
  .filter(el => el !== staticEl)
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)), staticEl];

console.log(sorted.map(el => el.name));
```